# My javascript code is printing only one row. I need it to print 10 rows of 20 characters.

Tags: javascript

This is a coin flipping randomizer. I need to print out 10 rows and 20 columns. This is where I am stuck. My code seems to randomize correctly every time I click my button, it displays 20 columns but I cannot seem to get it to print a second row. It may be something simple that I am just not catching. Anything will be appreciated.

Javascript Code

```
function toss()
{
var heads = "x ";
var tails = "o ";
var rows = 0;
while(rows < 10)
{   
    var arr = new Array(20);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {       
        var val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
        if(val === 1)
        {
            arr[i] = " x";
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = " y";
        }   
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = arr + "<br />";
    }
    delete arr;
    rows++
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Coin Flip</title>
<script src="Toss.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
<style>
#results
{
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
Push Button to Flip -> <input type="button" onclick="toss()" value=" Flip ">
<span id="results"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Please do not post answers as comments. Write an _answer_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are replacing the entire results output each time you create a row with the new row. You need to append instead of replace. So change this:

`document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = arr + "<br />";`

To:

`document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += arr + "<br />";`

You also need to move the append of the result out of the inner for loop! If you leave the append within the `for` loop, you will see this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/t1s93Lqz/3/

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t1s93Lqz/2/

Comment: This worked perfect. I see what was happening now. One question though. I got it working without this line `document.getElementById('toss').onclick = toss;`. What is this for?

Comment: @GiBiT09 It's only for JSFiddle -- it wasn't hooking up the function right when using the onclick on the tag. You can ignore that part. It's just another way to set what the onclick of the tag would run.

Comment: Ok thank you much for the answer. You get the green check.

Answer (score 2):

You are only printing the last row. Replace

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = arr + "<br />";
```

with

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += arr + "<br />";
```

Comment: Sorry! I edited the wrong answer when someone distracted me. I'll try to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the html inside the element each iteration through the loop

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = arr + "<br />";
```

And while you could concatenate innerHTML each iteration to fix this:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += arr + "<br />";
```

This will cause the whole html for that element to be re-rendered. It would be better to either build the html string first and then set the element's innerHTML property or use DOM methods like appendChild/insertAdjacentHTML.

Build string first

```
var html = "";
while(rows < 10)
{   
    var arr = new Array(20);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {       
        var val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
        if(val === 1) {
            arr[i] = " x";
        } else {
            arr[i] = " y";
        }   
    }
    //moved the concatenation out of the loop
    //otherwise you will get a line each as the array is set
    html += arr + "<br />";
    rows++
}
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html;
```

Using [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```
var element = document.getElementById("results");
while(rows < 10)
{   
    var arr = new Array(20);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {       
        var val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
        if(val === 1) {
            arr[i] = " x";
        } else {
            arr[i] = " y";
        }   
    }
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',arr+"<br />");
    rows++
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var rows = 0;
var element = document.getElementById("results");

while(rows < 10)
{   
  var arr = new Array(20);
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {       
    var val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
    if(val === 1) {
      arr[i] = " x";
    } else {
      arr[i] = " y";
    }   
  }
  element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',arr+"<br />");
  rows++
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Also note your `delete` statement won't do anything as [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) works on object properties, if you `console.log( delete arr )` you will see it will print `false`